# IEC socket rated for 250V at 10A - can it be used for 13A @230v?

Tags: ac

I'm building a relay board which I'll eventually control using an Arduino. I'm using an IEC socket so that I can use a simple kettle lead for my AC input. The appliance the relay is controlling might be drawing 13Amp. Can I still use this IEC socket?

According to my calculations I can't because at 13amp it's 2.9Kw not 2.5Kw. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 16A version of the IEC connector, known as a C19 type

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot be safely used.  The socket does not dissipate any significant power, so it doesn't care about the product of voltage and current.  (It doesn't care about the voltage at all, as long as it's low enough to avoid dielectric breakdown... and that would require thousands of volts.)

The only important parameter is the current rating, and that's 10 amps for the case you're referring to.  10 amps through the socket will heat it up just as much at 1 volt as it will at 5,000 volts.

Comment: Ok. Can you even get ones that are 13A? If not whats the alternative? I can't seem to find any at rs